# How to get port number of database in postgresql for ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using `postgresql 9.3` on `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. I know that the default port number for postgres is 5432. But, in case if it is different from the default one, then how can I get it?

Comment: this will find more answers on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you installed PostgreSQL and how it was configured.

There might even be multiple instances of PostgreSQL 9.3 on the machine - zero or more from Ubuntu packages, managed via `pg_wrapper`, and zero or more from other sources like the EDB graphical installer, compiled from source, etc.

Assuming you're only interested in packaged versions managed by `pg_wrapper` and you only expect there to be one version: use `pg_lsclusters`.

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.2 main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log
9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

e.g.

```
pg_lsclusters -h | awk '/^9.3/ { if ($2 == "main") { print $3; } }'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep postgres
```

Comment: Yes it works! But it is showing only when I'm logging-in as root.

Answer (score 2):

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'port'
```

- if you have multiple servers in the same cluster then use

  `select inet_server_port();`

Comment: That's only useful if you already know the port to connect to, though. So it's kind of a catch-22. You can't assume that the default port is the one you want - it depends on how the machine is set up, and it might well connect to some other PostgreSQL instance by default.